# Flutter app is crash when adding YoutubePlayer in some cases

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I used [youtube_player_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter) to load youtube video.But in some cases app is crash when i open the screen containing youtube video .Some time it working perfectly.
I got the below exception,

```
[ERROR:flutter/fml/platform/android/jni_util.cc(204)] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Platform view hasn't been initialized from the platform view channel.
```

Code to load youtube video ,

```
YoutubePlayer(
                      controller: YoutubePlayerController(
                        initialVideoId: YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(
                                controller.reelsList[index].url.toString())
                            .toString(),
                        flags: const YoutubePlayerFlags(
                            autoPlay: false,
                            mute: false,
                            hideControls: false,
                            showLiveFullscreenButton: false),
                      ),
                      showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
                    )
```

```
 compileSdkVersion 33
 minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i got the same trouble some weeks ago when i was implementing the same feature.

First, run on your terminal:

```
flutter clean
```

then

```
flutter pub get
```

then build your application again

This did the work for me,
By the way, i got some trouble with useHybridComposition making my app laggy on my physic device, so i've set it to false.

I've implemented this way, but i don't really think your code have any mistakes at all;

```
YoutubePlayer(
  controller: YoutubePlayerController(
    initialVideoId: videoModel.url,
    flags: const YoutubePlayerFlags(
        useHybridComposition: false,
        mute: false,
        autoPlay: false,
        disableDragSeek: true,
        loop: false,
        isLive: false,
        forceHD: false,
        enableCaption: false,
        showLiveFullscreenButton:
            false),
  ),
  showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
  progressIndicatorColor:
      colorScheme.secondary,
  progressColors: progressColors,
),
```

Update me, we can discuss further if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: man, the ```useHybridComposition``` seems to be crutial when using on Flutter module attached to native Android or iOS app.